# Stylus Path alias cannot be used in @import in @media

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stylus

I want to make a responsive layout using `stylus`. In order to facilitate maintenance, I have `@import` different files under `@media`, like the following:

```html
<style scoped lang="stylus">
    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px)
        @import '~styles/test1'
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
        @import '~styles/test2'
</style>
```

But the problem has arisen, `@import` seems to have mistakenly identified `~` as part of the path. As Below:

```
   1| <style scoped lang="stylus">
   2| @media screen and (min-width: 1024px)
   3|     @import '~styles/test1'
------------------^
   4| @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
   5|     @import '~styles/test2'
   6| </style>

failed to locate @import file ~styles/test1.styl
```

I configured an alias in `vue.config.js`, and `@import` works fine without `@media`.

```html
// no error
<style scoped lang="stylus">   
    @import '~styles/test1'
</style>
```

Below is my `vue.config.js` configuration:

```
const join = require('path').join

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: './',
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.alias
           .set('styles', join(__dirname, 'src/styles'))
    }
}
```

Below is the version list I used:

- vue `2.5.17`
- vue-cli `3.5.5`
- stylus `0.54.5`
- stylus-loader `3.0.2`

What caused this problem? Or do I have a better way to achieve responsiveness?